# Error messages in newsletters

Tags: error, images, newsletter, outlook

I use CIVI to send newsletters for my organisation. When the receiver opens the newsletter in the outlook app or on a mac they receive an error message. It seems to work for those opening the newsletter in Office 365 and through their browser as it doesn't appear.

[image]

The error message or error image appears as a sort of trace for the drafting of the newsletter. Where I have deleted an image or a text box in editing the newsletter, that's where the error appears.

Would really appreciate any take or tips on how to fix this!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Ellyse! Could you specify the error that is displayed (e.g. take a screenshot) and/or add some more details about what is working? Otherwise it will be difficult for others to help you efficiently ^^

Comment: Hi Fabian, thank you for the suggestion. I have added an example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the images may not have been deleted properly.

To test this - create a new email, add a single line of text, then press the **Source** button on the formatting toolbar.  Note how it shows the HTML equivalent. Press **Source** again to go back to normal editing.

Next, add an image, look at the new source HTML.

Finally, delete the image.  Is the source HTML the same as before you added the image?  If not, you may be deleting the image incorrectly.  I typically backspace over it - without watching you work, it's hard to tell you what to do differently.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your help. I have tried to follow your steps but the source code does not change. I also can't backspace the image as it is in a separate block and needs to be deleted by clicking the specific delete block button. Does that make sense? All sections within the Mosaico template are blocks that I work on seperately. Thanks again! Any more suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't realized you're using Mosaico!  If you can edit your question to include a screenshot of what Mosaico looks like it may help.  Do you know what version of Mosaico you're using?  You can see it at **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**.  I use Mosaico a lot but have never seen something like this.